# Usage statitics of Google Play: phone app VS website

Tags: android, google-play

I am considering hiring a graphic designer to create a high res (1 024 x 500) "promotional" image for my app.

From my experience (browsing through other apps), I noticed that this kind of image is only shown in full size on the web version of the Google Play store.

In order to get a better feeling of what the ROI could be, I would really like to know **what percentage of app downloads is made through Google Play website** (VS. through the regular Android mobile app).

- Is this figure public ?
- Did you manage to get some stats by tracking the download origin from your own apps ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience (application with 300 000 downloads), less than 5% of the downloads come from Google Play website. I don't know about public figures, I got this data by tracking the Google Play installation referrers (utm_source=google is Google Play website).
This doesn't give me an exact count, because there are installs without referrers, but it helps getting a general idea.

Of course, what is valid for my app is maybe not for you. I'd say that the more people can find your Google Play page from Google search using keywords, the more you'll have downloads from the webpage. Most people browse the app store directly from their device.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this figure. It looks realistic, I suppose the global figures are not too far from this.